# How to split a ServletRequest .getParameterMap() effincietly? [Spring MVC,ServletRequest]

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-mvc, dictionary

The problem I want to pose to you today is something like this:

A request hits a controller (in a spring MVC environment), and in that controller I would like to somehow split the request parameters. My initial approach was to use the @ModelAttribute annotation

```
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute Mouse tom, @ModelAttribute Mouse jerry)
```

But with this approach how would I get the other parameters? And is this efficient?

So I would like to do something like this:

```
Mouse jerry = new Mouse();
BeanUtils.populate(jerry, request.getParameterMap());
//do something to remove the mice :) how?
Cat tom = new Cat();
BeanUtils.populate(cat, request.getParameterMap());
//do something to remove the cats how?
BeanUtils.populate(theRest, request.getParameterMap());
```

The end question is: How do I split the request into 3 different entities efficiently by traversing the list as few times as possible?

Thank you for reading this, and hopefully get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're asking how to deal with multiple objects in a handler method, and not actually splitting form/query parameters, yes?

Just use one model. Wrap Tom, Jerry and theRest in a new object:

```
class Foo {
  Cat tom;
  Mouse jerry;
  Bar theRest;    
  ...
}
```

and

```
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute Foo foo)
```

Spring MVC can [data bind](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) for you. You don't need BeanUtils.

Comment: And what if, I do not know that the Bar object will contain? For example the request will look like this: &cat.name=Tom&mouse.name=Jerry&unknownAttribute=abc&unknownAttribute2=dcf. How can I create the Foo class so that it contains only the unknown* attributes?

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly an addition to Neil McGuiguan's answer.

You must know that Spring MVC way of storing requests parameters in a model attribute ignores the name of the model attribute, but does honor hierarchical named below.

So you could have :

```
class Mouse {
    String name;
    ...
    // getters and setters omitted
}

class Cat {
    String name;
    ...
}

class Foo foo {
    Mouse jerry;
    Cat tom;
    ...
}
```

And in your HTML (could be generated through Spring MVC tags ...)

```
<form ...>
    <input type="text" name="jerry.name"/>
    <!-- other fields for jerry -->
    <input type="text" name="tom.name"/>
    <!-- ...-->
</form>
```

That way :

```
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute Foo foo, BindingResult result)
```

will automatically populate all your fields with appropriate request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Keep an utility to detect whether the key refers to a mouse, cat or none of these. Then iterate through the whole keyset and put these into corresponding map. Something like this

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : requestParamMap.entrySet()) {
    if (isMouse(entry.getKey())) {
      jerry.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue);
    } else if (isCat(entry.getKey())) {
      cat.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue);
    } else {
      theRest.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue);
    }
}
```

It's **NOT** `O(n)` but certainly the best you can do keeping things simple.